# how to make a circle in css and make it responsive as well?

Tags: html, css

I am designing a webpage using CSS. I have a grid containing a column in which I have two elements one is fixed sized circle(containing a text) and a paragraph align to the right of the circle.

I have already done the above part but it is not responsive. the size of the circle is not decreasing or increasing as per the size of the screen.

See the image to get what I am trying to achieve.

[image]

```css
.Circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  font-size: 14px;
  border: 1.5px solid #fbcfce;
}
.Circle span {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  display: block;
}
.main {
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 none;
}
.sidebar {
  width: 60px;
  height: 10px;
  float: left;
  overflow: none;
  line-height: 0;
  margin-right: 25px;
}
.page-wrap {
  width: 300px;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: 40px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1 vsa">
  <div class="row main">
    <span class="Circle sidebar span1" style="padding:29px 12px;">Verify</span> 
    <div class="page-wrap">
      Verify your student status using your institute ID card or Email ID.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: explain a little more about what you want to happen responsively?  the code you have currently doesn't seem to have any other responsivity.    Your .main is set to a specific width. and your .sidebar (circle) is an absolute width.

Comment: there's no selector `.Circle span` in your HTML-code

Comment: `.main {width: 800px;...` , `.sidebar {width: 60px;...`, `.page-wrap {width: 300px;...`. Everything has fixed width. Where are you going to achieve responsivity?

Comment: hey brah, columns go _inside_ of rows

Comment: May be my approach is wrong but what i exactly want to do is : i have to align a fixed size circle having a text(verify) and a paragraph (Verify your student status using your institute ID card or Email ID.) in a row in a such a way that both the circle and a paragraph will remain in row if i decrease/increase the screen size.

Comment: If the circle needs to keep its defined size, the only thing you have control over is the text next to it, and it will not look very good if you need it to be on the same row regardless of screen-size. Seems someone haven't really understood the meaning of "responsive" or understand how to write something that works cross-browser / cross-platform / cross-user. The specification is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what to tell you other than to try and form an understanding of the tools you are using and of CSS in general. I recommend not trying to use Bootstrap here.

Check out this snippet - should be everything you need.

```css
.Circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  border: 1.5px solid #fbcfce;
  position: absolue;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
}
.main {
  margin-left: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <span class="Circle">Verify</span>
  <p class="main">
    Verify your student status using your institute ID card or Email ID.
  </p>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ttq096db/1/

Answer (score 2):

- This example uses a pseudo element to create a responsive circle, in conjunction with flexboxes to help with centering.
  JSfiddle: [jsfiddle.net/nc2v9p8y](https://jsfiddle.net/nc2v9p8y/)

```css
.circle {
  width: 15%;
  min-width: 50px; /* circle can't get smaller than this */
  max-width: 150px; /* no bigger than this */
  margin-right: 15px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.circle::before {
  content: "";
  border: 1px solid #555;
  border-radius: 100%;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 100%;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.circle span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.text {
  display: inline-block;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

/* *********** */
html { height: 100%; width: 100%; }
body { height: 100%; width: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 5px; }
*, *::before, *::after { box-sizing: border-box; }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="circle">
    <span>Verify</span>
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    Enter some text here.
  </div>
</div>
```

---

- A simpler solution would be to use viewport.
  Though not very efficient... Perhaps it could be done better, I'm not sure...
  JSfiddle: [jsfiddle.net/mxzhbnam](https://jsfiddle.net/mxzhbnam/)

```css
.circle {
  width: 20vw;
  height: 20vw;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #555;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 15px;
  /*
  min-height: 50px;
  min-width: 50px;
  */
}

.circle span {
  line-height: 20vw;
}

.text {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="circle">
    <span>Verify</span>
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    Enter some text here.
  </div>
</div>
```

---

- If the only thing you need is a static size circle, then all you should do is make the `height` and `width` of the container equal, you can use `px` for that.